# Remove item from Stream with empty value

Tags: java, java-stream

how can I remove in my stream the `item.currencyDescription()` that has empty value.

```
currencyService.getAllCurrencies().stream().collect(LinkedHashMap::new, (map, item) -> map.put(Integer.toString(item.currency()), item.currencyDescription()), Map::putAll));
```

Comment: you can use ``filter`` along with  ``stream`` to filter the collection

Comment: @Holger yes! thats the purpose

Comment: So, as pratap said, insert a `filter`, e.g. `.filter(item -> !item.currencyDescription() .isEmpty())`, before the `collect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for as suggested in the comments.

```
Map<String, String> result = list.stream()
                   .filter(item->!item.currencyDescription().isBlank())
                   .collect(LinkedHashMap::new,
                         (map, item) ->map.put(Integer.toString(item.currency()), 
                         item.currencyDescription()),
                         Map::putAll);
```

In your case it may not make a difference but by using the collector parameters you can't control which `item` will be used in case of duplicates (your method takes the most recent one).  If you want to keep the first duplicate encountered you can do it like this.

```
Map<String,String> result = list.stream().filter(item->!item.currencyDescription().isBlank())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(item-> Integer.toString(item.currency()),
                   item->item.currencyDescription(),
                   (item1, item2)->item1,  // keep first duplicate
                   LinkedHashMap::new));
```